# Footer no se queda fijo abajo

Tags: html, css, footer

Intenté de todo pero no puedo hacer que el `footer` me deje de seguir cuando hago `scroll`, quiero que quede abajo de forma fija y que solo pueda verlo cuando llego al final de la página.

Intenté con `absolute` y con `static`, pero me sigue o se queda estático en  medio de la pantalla y no sé como bajarlo cuando se queda quieto ahí.

Este es el código de `html`:

```
<!-- no te redirige -->
        <div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="icon-menu" class="icon">


            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- muestra los producto -->
        <div id="container-products" class="container">

        </div>

        <footer class="subs">
            <div class="container-foot">
                <h2>queres recibir ofertas de Coca-Cola?</h2>
                <input class="search-input" placeholder="Email"/>
                <div class="hr"></div>
                <button class="boton-standar">subscribite</button>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.7.11/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="./js/productos.js"></script> -->
        <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
```

Este es el de `css`:

```
footer.subs {
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    background-image: url(https://i.gifer.com/KzDn.gif);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 400px 20px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

footer.subs input {
    background-color: transparent;
    max-width: 300px;
}
footer.subs .hr {
    margin: 15px 5px;
    width: 450px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo ver estas usando `position: fixed` esto hace que el elemento se quede pegado, además si solo quieres que este al final, no necesitas posicionarlo usando top, left, right o bottom  solo ponlo de ultimo, otra cosa css lee las propiedades en cascada, eso significa que la ultima propiedad que encuentre es la que se utiliza.

Comment: sisi, lo use en fixed, static, absolute, no importa en todos da error. Tambien entiendo lo de cascada